# TypeError: (‘Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row’, ‘HY000’) Error on pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to fetch all the duplicates from  tokens and load into tokn_Duplicates table. Getting Type error as below, if the sequence/format of the values passed to the insert query is causing this. Tried different options from the forum to pass the values as tuple/list, havent been successful

Code snippet below and error

```
 with conn.cursor() as cur:

cur.execute("""
           select case when tokn_type_cd IS NULL Then 'Address'  else tokn_type_cd end as tokn_type_cd,case when tokn_val_tx is null then '0' else tokn_val_tx end tokn_val_tx,case when pg_duplicate_ct is null then 0 else pg_duplicate_ct end  pg_duplicate_ct  from ((SELECT 0 DUMMY ) DM LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, COUNT(*) AS pg_duplicate_ct
      FROM   devt.tokens
      GROUP BY tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) on 1=1)
        """)
        rows2 = cur.fetchall()

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(server='connect to server')

crsr = cnxn.cursor()

if len(rows2):
    crsr.executemany("INSERT INTO duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [str(r) for r in rows2])
cnxn.commit()

print("... Successfully completed...")
```

Error received below

```
     
crsr.executemany(“INSERT INTO duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)“, [str(r) for r in rows2])
TypeError: (‘Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row’, ‘HY000’)
```

Tried the below change from the forum:

```
crsr.executemany(“INSERT INTO duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)“, [str(tokn_type_cd), str(tokn_val_tx) ,pg_duplicate_ct])
```

received the error below after the change

```
crsr.executemany(“INSERT INTO secret_tokn_duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)“, [str(tokn_type_cd), str(tokn_val_tx) ,pg_duplicate_ct])
NameError: name ‘tokn_type_cd’ is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
crsr.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO secret_tokn_duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    [(str(row.tokn_type_cd), str(row.tokn_val_tx), row.pg_duplicate_ct) for row in rows2])
```

or if that doesn't work:

```
crsr.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO secret_tokn_duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    [(str(row[0]), str(row[1]), row[2]) for row in rows2])
```

The list `[(str(row.tokn_type_cd), str(row.tokn_val_tx), row.pg_duplicate_ct) for row in rows2]` creates a list of 3-tuples from the rows in `rows2`. I don't have access to your database, so I can't test that it works, but it's my best guess at will work given what's in your question.

Your first attempt

```py
crsr.executemany("INSERT INTO duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [str(r) for r in rows2])
```

didn't work because the list you passed to `crsr.executemany` contained strings, which were what you got if you attempted to convert each row read from the cursor to a string. The elements in the list passed to `crsr.executemany` must be lists, tuples or Rows: you need to pass it a list of lists, a list of tuples or a list of Rows.

Your second attempt

```py
crsr.executemany("INSERT INTO duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [str(tokn_type_cd), str(tokn_val_tx) ,pg_duplicate_ct])
```

didn't work because `tokn_type_cd`, `tokn_val_tx` and `pg_duplicate_ct` aren't variables that Python knows about.  However, even if you had defined them, you would again end up passing a list of strings to `crsr.executemany` and would get the first error again.

---

However, having said all the above, most RDBMSs support `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statements, which will copy the data directly, so why not just execute the following?

```py
cur.execute("""
           INSERT INTO duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct)
           select case when tokn_type_cd IS NULL Then 'Address'  else tokn_type_cd end as tokn_type_cd,case when tokn_val_tx is null then '0' else tokn_val_tx end tokn_val_tx,case when pg_duplicate_ct is null then 0 else pg_duplicate_ct end  pg_duplicate_ct  from ((SELECT 0 DUMMY ) DM LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, COUNT(*) AS pg_duplicate_ct
      FROM   devt.tokens
      GROUP BY tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) on 1=1)
        """)
```

Comment: Apologies, there is a delete of rows from the duplicates table prior to inserting this data which i havent provided, My Bad. Hence execute would not be the approach to club select and insert in a single query. Tried running the script provided receiving the below error:                                                                                                    , line 47, in <listcomp>
  [(str(row.tokn_type_cd), str(row.tokn_val_tx), row.pg_duplicate_ct) for row in rows2])
AttributeError: ‘tuple’ object has no attribute ‘tokn_type_cd’

Comment: @Max: if you're getting tuples returned, then try using `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]` to get at the selected elements, as per the second code block above.

Comment: The second query worked fine..Woohoo..Thanks!   crsr.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO secret_tokn_duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    [(str(row[0]), str(row[1]), row[2]) for row in rows2])

Answer (score 0):

`rows2` is the result of a `.fetchall()` which means that it is a list of `pyodbc.Row` objects. Such a list is suitable without modification for use as parameters for a subsequent `.executemany()` operation. In other words, don't mess with `rows2`; just pass it to the `.executemany()` for your INSERT:

```py
if len(rows2):
    crsr.executemany(
        "INSERT INTO duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
        rows2
    )
cnxn.commit()
```

Your initial attempt failed because `[str(r) for r in rows2]` returns a list of string objects (scalars) instead of a list of Row objects.

Comment: Had tested this change earlier to pick rows2, however strangely received the below error. 
 crsr.executemany(“INSERT INTO duplicates (tokn_type_cd, tokn_val_tx, pg_duplicate_ct) VALUES (?, ?, ?)“, rows2)
pyodbc.Error: (‘HY004’, ‘[HY004] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)’)

Comment: Also the layout of the duplicates table is below if thats causing any error in insert                                        Column_Name       Data Type
-----------       ---------
tokn_type_cd      varchar(100)
tokn_val_tx       varchar(100)
pg_duplicate_ct   int